# sqoop free form query to import n records from a table

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm trying to import "50" records from a single table using the following query

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxx/db_name --username yyyyy --query 'select * from table where (id <50) AND $CONDITIONS' --target-dir /user/tmp/ -P
```

I'm having error on this query.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

i removed the parenthesis in where clause and it worked and when using two or more logical operators use parenthesis otherwise it doesn't work